# Bypass em tags when extracting contents of class name using Parsel selector

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, parsel

I'm trying to extract the contents of the class name. How to do I extract all the contents including the ones inside the 'em' tags and after the 'em' tags too? See picture below:

[image]
I tried the following and these were the results:

Trial 1:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
sel = Selector(text = driver.page_source)
sel.xpath("//*[@class ='st']").extract()
```

Output 1:

```
>> <span class="st"><span class="f">Nov 26, 2018 - </span>First #<em>GDPR fine</em> awarded in Germany. 330,000 user data stolen. Usernames and passwords stored in plaintext. €20,000 <em>fine</em>. Why "so low"?</span>
```

Trial 2:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
sel = Selector(text = driver.page_source)
sel.xpath("//*[@class ='st']/text()").extract()
```

Output 2:

```
>> First #
```

Ideally, the output I want to get is:

```
>> Nov 26, 2018 - First #GDPR fine awarded in Germany. 330,000 user data stolen. Usernames and passwords stored in plaintext. €20,000 fine. Why "so low"?
```

Comment: I don't know Parsel but have you tried something like `//*[@class='st']::text` or a CSS selector `span.st::text`? See [the docs](https://parsel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#extensions-to-css-selectors)

Comment: @JeffC Those expressions throw up errors. So far I've tried `sel.xpath("string(//span[@class = 'st'])").getall()` See [link](https://parsel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html). This works for extracting the full text but only returns the first list element, where I would ideally want a list of all matching class names in the page to be returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually found a way to solve the problem though not an elegant one, would still welcome a more elegant solution.

I pulled in the contents of the class name using:

```
 driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
 sel = Selector(text = driver.page_source)
 content = sel.xpath("//*[@class ='st']").extract()
```

I then defined a function that stripped the html away from the text:

```
import html.parser

class HTMLTextExtractor(html.parser.HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        super(HTMLTextExtractor, self).__init__()
        self.result = [ ]

    def handle_data(self, d):
       self.result.append(d)

    def get_text(self):
       return ''.join(self.result)

    def html_to_text(html):
        s = HTMLTextExtractor()
        s.feed(html)
        return s.get_text()
```

Looping through the contents in the list and stripping the html one at a time gave me the result I wanted:

```
  m = []
  for w in content:
      z = html_to_text(w)
      m.append(z)
```